# jQuery selector with concatenation not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, concatenation

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2

This line works fine on IE9, Chrome and Firefox:

```
$('.' + product.id + '#' + this).text("foo");
```

`product.id` being a string representing a class and `this` being a string representing an id.

The line is inside a $.each loop, I did not post the entire code of this function because it's rather large and the error is located exactly on this line.

An example of a selector dynamically created with this loop would be:

```
$('.price#servicesPerMonth').text("foo");
```

In IE8 I get the following error:

```
Unexpected call to method or property access.  
jquery-1.7.2.js, line 5847 character 5
```

The code in jQuery is this one:

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
            this.appendChild( elem );
        }
    });
},
```

Line 5847 is `this.appendChild( elem );`

I think the problem is coming from concatenating the `this` variable in the jQuery selector, but I don't really know an alternative to fix this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's `this`? A string?

Comment: Why do you use class and id? Simply using id must be enough because your html has unique ids, right?

Comment: Is the target element by any a chance a html5 element, such as `section`? I can reproduce this in IE8 when I use a html5 element without shims

Comment: Yes, `this` is a string, and the target element is not a html5 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
('.' + product.id + ' #' + this.id).text("foo");
```

or

```
('.' + product.id + ' #' + this.attr('id')).text("foo");
```

It will be fine, notice the space before #

Comment: How do you know there needs to be a space between the class selector and ID selector? And how do you know what `this` is? The OP needs to update the question before you can know whether your answer is even close.

Comment: ah, my bad, I thought this is an object. But this is a keyword, you can not use this to save string values, better use any other name

Comment: @Sachin Wrong: You can set `this` to a string: `(function(){return this}).call("test")` returns a `String` object.`(function(){'use strict';return this}).call("test")` returns a primitive string.